# Floating Action Button from support library custom animation (pre lollipop)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-compatibility

I add rotate animation to simulate circular progress bar for time consuming operations started by FAB. It working nicely on Lollipop, but animation does not start on KitKat. Any glue? Thanks.

- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
- minSdkVersion 16
- compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1
- compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/review_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    />
```

MyFragment.java

```
       @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
        button = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.review_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startLongOperation();
                doLongOperation();
            }
        });
        // Delayed show button animation start
        button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.show();
            }
        }, 250);
        return view;
    }

    /** Disable form and show progress */
    protected void startLongOperation() {
        button.setClickable(false);
        button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.LTGRAY));
        button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.rotate));
        text.setEnabled(false);
        ...
    }

    /** Enable form and stop progress */
    protected void stopLongOperation() {
        if (null != getActivity()) {
            button.setClickable(true);
            button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.zelena)));
            button.clearAnimation();
            text.setEnabled(true);
            ...
        }
    }
    }

    public void doLongOperation() {
         ...
         // call stop animation when finished
         stopLongOperation();
    }
```